# How to get the selected contactProperty from CNContactPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cncontactpicker

I'm currently able to get a contact from the contacts app, but the problem I'm facing that I need to be able to select the contact I want to import to my app , if the contact have more than 1 phone number, I always get the first number, here is the code I'm using:

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {

    let numbers     = contactProperty.contact.phoneNumbers.first
    let firstName   = contactProperty.contact.givenName
    let lastName    = contactProperty.contact.familyName
    let phoneNumber = (numbers?.value)?.stringValue ?? ""

    /// Duplicate phone numbers will not be saved
    if phoneNumbers.contains(phoneNumber) {
        return
    }
    /// Saving selected contact in Core Data
    CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.savePhoneNumberInCoreData(FirstName: firstName, LastName: lastName, PhoneNumber: phoneNumber)

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The problem with line:

```
contactProperty.contact.phoneNumbers.first
```

There are two options only for `contactProperty.contact.phoneNumbers` `.first` or `.last`

If there is something like `.selected`, it would solve the problem.

Comment: Do you tap the contact name or one of the phone numbers of the contact(is that possible?)?

Comment: phoneNumbers is an array. You're getting a single number because you're picking the first object of the array. Use array as a whole instead.

Comment: @PGDev, she want only one number from list which is save as primary number.

Comment: Using (_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact)
enabled to select the contact only.

Using (_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty)
Enabled me to open the contact and view the phone numbers in it and select one, but regardless of what I select, I always get the first number.

Comment: @Jessica, any way you managed to solve this? I'm having the same issue.
I don't want to present the numbers on the array to the user since he/she just clicked the number they want to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called Main telephone number that you could use

```
var phoneNumber: String?

if let mainNumber = numbers.first(where: { $0.label == CNLabelPhoneNumberMain }) {
    phoneNumber = mainNumber.value.stringValue
} else {
    phoneNumber = numbers.first?.value.stringValue //or some other default value
}
```

Note that I changed the definition of `numbers` to be the array of phone numbers

```
let numbers = contactProperty.contact.phoneNumbers
```

---

Full code:

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {

    let numbers = contactProperty.contact.phoneNumbers    
    var phoneNumber: String?

    if let mainNumber = numbers.first(where: { $0.label == CNLabelPhoneNumberMain }) {
        phoneNumber = mainNumber.value.stringValue
    } else {
        phoneNumber = numbers.first?.value.stringValue //or some other default value
    }

    if phoneNumber == nil || phoneNumbers.contains(phoneNumber) {
        return
    }

    let firstName = contactProperty.contact.givenName
    let lastName = contactProperty.contact.familyName   

    CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.savePhoneNumberInCoreData(FirstName: firstName, LastName: lastName, PhoneNumber: phoneNumber)

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: This kind of response is so annoying, how can I ever improve my answer with a reply like "it didn't work"?

Comment: It have compiler errors, everything should be unwrapped. even with that, it didn't work. Maybe you can show how to implement your code in an example?

Comment: Thanks Joakim, the code works, I just had to replace numbers.first to numbers.last  in your example: 
else {
            phoneNumber = numbers.last?.value.stringValue //or some other default value
        }

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, this solution only works in scenarios where the phone number labels match the assumptions.

Comment: @benc What assumptions do you mean? It makes use of the phone number that is selected as the main phone number, not of any labels.

Comment: oh, I see you are preferring a number labeled "main"...

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with solution of Joakim Danielson.

But there are one more solution to get specific phone number which is stored in mobile number like home, mobile, fax etc.

Get all numbers from contact and enumerate on every number and check labeled values. See following code.

```
let numbers = contact.phoneNumbers

numbers.forEach { (c) in

    if let label = c.label {

        let localizedLabel = CNLabeledValue<NSCopying & NSSecureCoding>.localizedString(forLabel: label)
        print("\(localizedLabel)")

        switch localizedLabel.lowercased() {

        case "home":
            let homeNumber = c.value
            break

        case "mobile":
            let mobileNumber = c.value
            break

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`contactProperty.contacts` is a back-reference to the `CNContact` the selected property lives in...

> Each property is represented by an instance of CNContactProperty, which provides a tuple that can contain three or five values, depending on whether the property is a member of an array of labeled values.
> [CNContactProperty](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactproperty)

So, you should use the property's Information `var`s directly:

> For example, the phoneNumbers property is a member of an array of labeled values, so the CNContactProperty tuple contains the contact, key, value, identifier, and label.
>
> [CNContactProperty](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactproperty)

NOTE: I learned this from reading another S-O answer, but I can't seem to find it right now. If appropriate, dupe or edit thus,